# Am I just considered a tourist, and am I able to leave and return to the UK while on that free tourism visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa, working, canadian-citizens

I'm a young (20) Canadian visiting the UK, and staying with a family free of charge in exchange for babysitting their children for about three hours a day. They provide me with pocket money, but no formal wage, which I will use (along with some savings) to explore the country. I plan to base myself in London, with a decent bit of weekend travels to other countries. I have a flight there booked for September, and a return flight booked for December. I then will return in January, and leave the UK for good at the end of February. Do any of you foresee any problems with my arrangement? I live in Winnipeg, and the long term visa requirements must be fulfilled in Toronto, so it would be quite unrealistic for me to spend $1,000 on a round-trip flight to Toronto simply for them to scan my fingerprints.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96370/discussion-on-question-by-dani-am-i-just-considered-a-tourist-and-am-i-able-to).

Comment: You're lucky enough to be from one of the few countries eligible for a [Tier 5 Youth Mobility visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility). You should apply for that rather than risk being deported.

Comment: I recommend you search for “uk au pair visa”, this should give you all the details (your arrangement is called being an “au pair”).

Answer (score 9):

The big problem that I see with this arrangement is that the UK considers it work -- and it is; you will literally be working for compensation -- and will not allow you to enter for that purpose without a work visa.

Comment: Punctuation in this answer is as neat as it’s content!

Comment: I can't help it. I've been a writer for much longer than I've been anything else.